# "Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location" error with Firefox in Robot Framework

Tags: python, firefox, robotframework

I'm currently learning to use Robot and have run into an error that I'm not sure how to get around. Running my file I receive a `SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line` error.

My code:

```
Documentation  Basic info
Library  SeleniumLibrary

***Variables***

***Test Cases***
Open and close browser
    [Documentation]  Test info
    [Tags]  Smoke
    Open Browser  http://www.amazon.com chrome
    Close Browser

***Keywords***
```

I'm not even using Firefox in my code, I'm using Chrome. I installed Firefox and I still get the error, I also tried using Firefox in the code and the error remained. Firefox was installed in the default location of `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox`, this was the default location when I installed Firefox and I have restarted my system. This question is really two questions:

1. Why am I getting an error that Firefox can't be located when I'm not even trying to use Firefox?
2. Now that I installed Firefox, why isn't Robot able to find the executable?

Comment: You only have one space before `chrome` in the question. Is that how it is on your system? That might explain why it's using firefox.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to use the spaces after key words.

> > Open Browser ***[ADD 2 Spaces Here]*** HTTP://www.amazon.com ***[ADD 2 Spaces Here]*** chrome

`Open Browser    http://www.amazon.com    edge`